# How to use top-level functions in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Suppose I have a class like.

```dart
class PrintService{
  void hello(){
    print('hello');
  }
}
```

In the case of a class with only one method like this, should I delete the class and define it as a top-level function like the one below? Or is it better not to abuse top-level functions and basically define methods in classes?

`fileName: print_service.dart`

```dart
  void hello(){
    print('hello');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's personal preference but generally it's better to define method in class, because it's easier for dependency injection later.Also, it's more maintainable as you don't have to break an existing code next time when you wanna add second method to the class.